# Using Oledb connection string for Localhost c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, oledb

When use Oledb c# connection
I noticed that a lot connection using file.
But how to connect to localhost using oledb?
I created database and tables using Microsoft SQL Server Management that connect with SQL Express and using window authentication

When using this function i don't know how should convert to connect to localhost

```
//Want the connString to connect localhost instead of file
public static string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + Path + "\\database\\errDB.mdb";
public static OleDbConnection connection;

public myFunction()
{
    string sqlString = "SELECT name,contact,accessLevel,Crudential_ID FROM errors where Crudential_ID =@ID";
    connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, connection);

    //Open connection
    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = "test";

    //Read from database
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
       .....
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) - true to its name - is indispensable when you frequently need to construct connection strings. For your specific case, [this would be the relevant section](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/).

Based on that, your connection string should look something like this:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SOMEDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

To break it down:

- `SQLNCLI11` is the *SQL Native Client* OLEDB provider. You can see available providers in *SQL Management Studio*, under *Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers*.
- `.\SQLEXPRESS` is your servername and instance. The `.` is shorthand for `localhost` (you can also use `localhost` if you prefer), and `SQLEXPRESS` is the default instance name that SQL Express installs under.
- `SOMEDATABASE` - whatever your database name is.
- `Trusted_Connection=yes` - Use windows authentication. Sometime you see it as `Integrated Security=SSPI`. They are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Express then I would suggest using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` object to make your connection. You will only need your server name to connect.

```
Server=ServerName\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Blah;User ID=user;Password=pw
```

Comment: This is also a good answer. See this thread for OLEDB vs SqlConnection: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fadb2742-d75a-49fb-a839-b2d4a9183998/oledbconnection-vs-sqlconnection  It all boils down to flexibility vs. speed.